# Find where the function are holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find by the Cauchy-Riemann equations where the functions $f(z)=\tan(z)$, $g(z)=(z-1)^{-10}$  and $h(z)=e^{2z-z^3}$ are holomorphic. How can I proceed?. In the case of $f$, I think to use where $\sin(z)=0$ and take off that complex numbers $z$, but in the next cases I don't know how to proceed. Can you help me?

Comment: $g(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)^{10}}$ is not very different to $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}$. The idea really is that the composition of holomorphic functions works well.

Comment: I know, but my problem is that I have to use the Cauchy Riemann equations, and for the 10th power is very difficukt to express, i think that would be some hint or something to reduce that expresion.

Comment: There is all you need : sum and product of holomorphic functions are holomorphic. Also if $F(z)$ is holomorphic on $U$ and $G(z)$ is holomorphic on $F(U)$ then $G(F(z))$ is holomorphic on $U$ (prove it !). Let $G(z) = 1/z$, it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^*$.